# Why does my Jupyter give me a ModuleNotFound error for a fortran code compiled in f2py?

Tags: python, installation, fortran, package, f2py

My Jupyter notebook gives me a ModuleNotFound error for a fortran code compiled in f2py. The f2py is in a make.sh file that I run as part of installation of a package. Some info

1. which f2py $ 'user/anaconda3/envs/petitRT/bin/f2py'
2. which python $ 'user/anaconda3/envs/petitRT/bin/python'
3. python --version $ Python 3.7.9
4. the make.sh file has  $ f2py -c --opt='-O3 -funroll-loops -ftree-vectorize -ftree-loop-optimize -msse -msse2 -m3dnow' -m fort_rebin fort_rebin.f90
5. the .so file created is named $ 'fort_rebin.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
6. Lastly, which jupyter $ 'user/anaconda3/envs/petitRT/bin/jupyter'

Could someone help me solve this mystery?

Some edits:
The make.sh file and fort_rebin.f90 are in the upmost/directory.

The fortran code I need to import is in inner/directory/rebin_give_width.f90. The package installation however doesn't say anything about compiling rebin_give_width.f90(also not mentioned in make.sh). I now see that it doesnt have any .so file generated.

The thing is, this lib worked before. I reinstalled the package for some other reason and something happened.

Calling the lib and error-

$ import rebin_give_width as rgw

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import rebin_give_width as rgw

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rebin_give_width'

Okay I found a workaround. I'm not sure why it worked before and I'm not sure why its not part of the installation. However, I included the command $ f2py -c inner/directory/rebin_give_width.f90 -m rebin_give_width  in make.sh and the statement $ import upmost_directory.rebin_give_width now works!!

Comment: Welcome. How do you load the library in Python? The call and the complete error message would help.